# Software for tournaments, leaderboards and result tracking

Tags: software, tournament

guys,

What kind of software/apps do you use to track your results of games with friends or in clubs?

How do you track your wins/losses and progress while casually playing chess?

Comment: Quick clarification: are you looking for software to store your *games*, or your *results*? I know some players like to keep a "running total" of their results and "real-time" ELO - is this what you are asking about? For games I would agree with ryan-cook that SCID is a reasonable choice, for results I simply use Excel.

Comment: Yeah, the question sounds more like he is interested in the results and some kind of rating and not so much a game archive.

Comment: True. I'm more interested in software to keep tracking leaderboards and game results in general. Game archive would be a nice feature although.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend SCID. It's free and works on any operating system, and there are even mobile versions available.

As far as recording your games during casual play, I would just use regular score sheets and enter them in the computer later. If you play online, sites like Chess.com let you download your games in PGN format, which can be imported into SCID or other database software.

Most people who use databases prefer to only include their tournament games, since casual games are going to show patterns that might not apply when you're playing serious chess. You could keep them in a separate database if you really want to record everything.

For fun, see how much of a casual game you can play back from memory after the game is over. You will remember more if:

1. You are consistent with the openings you play.
2. Your moves follow a general plan.
3. You actively concentrate on what is happening on the board, how you got there, and where you're headed. This keeps the sequence of moves fresh and connected, for reconstructing later.